# asp.net page load time

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is that how to maintained page load time in c#

and what page time load is good for site to crawl google index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is that how to maintained page load time in c#

Use the **Cache** object and **output caching** as much as possible. Less requests to expensive resources like files, databases, webservices, ... can be reduced in such a way speeding up performance and response time. Of course you need to measure each little bit of effort you're doing in that.

There's also a book available which might be of interest to you: [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET: Building Ultra-Fast and Ultra-Scalable Websites Using ASP.NET and SQL Server](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430223839).

> and what page time load is good for site to crawl google index

I have no idea about the inner workings of google but I assume that increased speed is the best, also do something about your **SEO** and have a sitemap of your site ready.